# What does this statement mean? "ret += (sx+ey)%2 ? 3 : 1, sx++;"

Tags: c++

What does the statement is doing I've mentioned?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;

int64_t dist(int64_t sx, int64_t sy, int64_t ex, int64_t ey) {
    sx += ey - sy;
    int64_t ret = (ey - sy)*2;
    if (sx%2 != ex%2)   
        ret += (sx+ey)%2 ? 3 : 1, sx++; // i don't understand this line,Please explain it.
    ret += (ex - sx)*2;
    return ret;
```

Comment: The one that wrote this is trying to make things unreadable.

Comment: If `(sx+ey)%2` is 1, then add 3 to `ret` otherwise add 1 to `ret`. Then increment `sx`

Comment: It's pretty terrible style, and is used just to avoid putting braces around the `if` block

Comment: You can look up what `?`, `%` and the `,` operator do and you'll understand.

Comment: Apart from what it compiles to, this line means that the author hates other people.

Comment: It's pretty racy even by my standards. If you (or maintainers of your code) don't know what sequencing points are, and the fact that ? and : are sequencing points in the ternary conditional, that the bit between ? and : is evaluated as if it's in parentheses, then refrain from using such an expression.

Comment: Hi! Is this a homework assignment? If so, it might be designed as a puzzle for you to investigate and figure about. As @SkyZip pointed out, you probably should read about those operators.

Comment: I guess the `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` gives a hint this might be taken from a competitive programming site. Hence, the author might not have cared about `ret += (sx+ey)%2 ? 3 : 1, sx++;` concerning readability for humans. ;-)

Comment: I'm sure this function could be rewrote with a oneliner

Comment: I wonder about the down-votes. Yes, all these things can be found by research but that's true for most of the questions in SO. There seems to be a consens that the remarked expression is hard to read. So, for an entry-level programmer, this can be a real challenging task with high chances to get lost. I can understand that OP found this worth a question.

Comment: @Arafat Code written like this is badly written. Obfuscation like this should not be done in professional code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a ternary conditional operator that lets you avoid multi-statement `if`-`else` construction while assigning a value to a variable.
The form of using it is

`variable = condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`.

`+=` operator adds a value to some variable and is equal to `ret = (ret + (sx+ey)%2 ? 3 : 1, sx++);`

`%` operator is used to compute a remainder of two numbers.

`++` is used to add `1` to a given variable and in your case it executes right after adding `1` to `ret` (if that condition on that line is false).

Anyway this code is really unreadable as noted in the comments, nothing bad will happen if we break it into several statements.

```cpp
if (sx % 2 != ex % 2) { 
  if ((cx + ey)) % 2) {
    ret += 3;
  } else {
    ret++;
  }
  sx++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is quite compact.

To understand it, you must be familiar with the <s>less</s> not so common operators [`%` (modulo)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Multiplicative_operators) and [`?:` (conditional)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) as well as the [operator precedences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Not to mention that integral values can be used as booleans ([`0` → `false`, anything else → `true`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions)).

And finally, the [`,` (sequence operator)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) to concatenate expressions, with the last one providing the final result, (which is in this case just discarded, so that only the side effects are used).

```
ret += (sx+ey)%2 ? 3 : 1, sx++; // i don't understand this line,Please explain it.
```

can be written in a less compact form:

```
if (((sx + ey) % 2) != 0) { // Is the sum of sx and ey odd (not even)
  ret += 3; // add 3 to ret
} else {
  ret += 1; // add 1 to ret
}
++sx; // increment sx
```